# palindrome just using loops in C

Tags: c, loops, palindrome

I used following code..but i am looking for proper condition to put. please help me out with it.

```
int main(){
    int k = 0;
    char a[9] = {'\0'}, b[9] = {'\0'};

    printf("enter string \n");
    gets(a);
    int p = strlen(a);

    for(int i = p-1; i >= 0; i--){
        b[k] = a[i];
        k = k+1;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < p; j++){
        if(a[j] == b[j]){
            continue;
        }else
            printf("not pal");

        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `proper condition` ?

Comment: i think i am doing right.but don't know what to do when both string matches..

Comment: You have a serious stack-overflow issue (oh the irony)

Comment: just look at this code as palindrome code using loops.

Comment: thats why i am asking for help naa..

Comment: @user2980181 for that case it would be better to keep track by setting `flag` and then print yes and no for palindrome on the basis of flag value

Comment: @user2980181: You can do your homework exercise with 1 loop and no copying. Small advice, when writing expressions, don't be cheap with whitespace.

Comment: @user2980181 so once you arrive just before return you may want to check if the strings were equal. Easiest is to e.g. count the number of characters that differ, if 0 it was a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int j=0;j<p;j++)
{
      if(a[j]!=b[j])
      {
          printf("not pal");
          return 0;
      }
}
printf("string is Palindrome");
return 0;
```

Comment: doing his homework for him does not help him in the long run.

Comment: I am sorry for that. Shall I remove the answer ?

Comment: @claptrap: There's the "learn by example" argument, but yes I think an explanation is the more appropriate way to teach.

Comment: @KaustavRay no.. no need to remove answer. just add some explanation what you have added and why and what the OPs answer lacked

Comment: @KaustavRay no point now, maybe you could elaborate more on it so that the guy understands it better than just copy the solution and move on.

Comment: thanks all...but @sansix showed me the way long before..i also don't need the code.what i want i got it before only..so thanks sansix and other guys too..

Comment: @claptrap high five :)

Comment: @claptrap if its a homework..then there are lakhs of website where i can get its answer..with full code..why do i try to get help here and try to make this code just by using loops..i can straight a way use strcpy and strrev function to build this code..well thanks

Comment: @user2980181 normally when people come with such artificial constraints it is due to their teacher being "clever" -  whether or not it is homework is besides the point anyway, best learning is by doing so keep up the good work.

Comment: @claptrap thanks buddy..thing is just that i am making my fundamentals clear in strings..if you do have any suggestions please share..

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy the string. The code below uses the size of the whole string to copy the mirrored letter and checks for equality. Complexity is `O(N/2)` (if that even exists `:-p`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_palindrome(const char* s)
{
  const size_t len = strlen(s);
  size_t i=0;
  while(i<len/2-1)
  {
    if(s[i] != s[len-i-1])
      return false;

    ++i;
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  const char* s1 = "palindrome";
  const char* s2 = "palindromemordnilap";

  if(is_palindrome(s1))
    printf("uhoh");
  if(is_palindrome(s2))
    printf("yay!");
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a4fb1a6a969fc4f).

Comment: i am not that good at pointers thats why i didn't follow such way..but thanks buddy

Comment: @user2980181 there are not really pointers here. This is just accessing the string as an array through `[]`. It would be similar in C++ with a proper `std::string` and `operator[]`.